# Passing a password (cat) to sed to replace config value

Tags: bash, sed, password

I have a config file called `.env` which contains:

`DB_PASSWORD={password}`

Within `/root/.mysql/db00.yml.db` we have a password for the MySQL root account. I'm trying to pipe this into `sed` along the lines of:

```bsh
cat /root/.mysql/db00.yml.db | sed -i -e "s/DB_PASSWORD=/DB_PASSWORD=(.*)/g" .env
```

Not having any luck, tried a few variations like:

```bsh
sed -i "s/DB_PASSWORD=/DB_PASSWORD=$(cat /root/.mysql/db00.yml.db)" .env
```

```bsh
mysqlpwd=$(cat /root/.mysql/db00.yml.db)
# Use the variable in sed -i
sed -i "s/DB_PASSWORD=/DB_PASSWORD=$mysqlpwd/g" .env
```

This produces the error:

```
root@linuxbox:/var/www/www.example.com# mysqlpwd=$(cat /root/.mysql/db00.yml.db)
root@linuxbox:/var/www/www.example.com# sed -i "s/DB_PASSWORD=/DB_PASSWORD=$mysqlpwd/g" .env
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
```

**Update:**

Running it without `/g` also fails:

```
root@linuxbox:/var/www/www.example.com# echo $mysqlpwd
Rjcr/Sn+s/a2QbGx
root@linuxbox:/var/www/www.example.com# cat .env | grep DB_PASSWORD
DB_PASSWORD=(.*)()
root@linuxbox:/var/www/www.example.com# sed -i "s/DB_PASSWORD=/DB_PASSWORD=$mysqlpwd/" .env
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
```

None of these approaches seem to work.

I am running `sed 4.7`, i.e.:

```
root@linuxbox:/var/www/www.example.com# sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.7
```

Comment: Try putting a `/` after the _pwd_ in your last example.

Comment: Assuming this is linux ... if it's OSX you need to add a suffix after the -i.

Comment: Yep, Debian 10.8. @Mr R: good pick up but the latter with `/g` seems to fail also.

Comment: You can't do his with `sed` in general, without being _really careful_ with sanitizing user input (the data read from the file) so that it doesn't break the `sed` syntax (a single `/` in the password would do that), or worse, so that it doesn't accidentally overwrite existing files (`/;w /ets/passwd;s//`) or execute arbitrary code (`reboot/e;s//`). It would be _a lot easier_ with `awk`. Also, *never work logged in as root*!!!

Comment: You don't need a /g you surely don't have password= multiple times on the same line.  You might be having an issue because of the characters in the password matching what sed is using ... IF you know a character that isn't used in the password / isn't allowed then use that ...e.g. if `|` couldn't be used then `sed -i "|DB_PASSWORD=|DB_PASSWORD=$mysqlpwd|"

Comment: @JamesSpittal if still having problems - confirm you actually have a value in mysqlpwd .. ie. echo $mysqlpwd

Comment: @Kusalananda how would we implement similar functionality in `awk`? I agree about never work logged in as root (but this is for an install script in a environment that doesn't exist essentially).

Comment: @MrR: echo $mysqlpwd produces the randomly generated password as you can see above. Leaving /g off doesn't seem to make any difference. I'll try `|`.

Comment: Hmm: `sed -i "|DB_PASSWORD=|DB_PASSWORD=$mysqlpwd|" .env` produces the error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'`.

Comment: @jamesSpittal sorry - I missed the `s` off the start of the command ... so `sed -i "s|DB_PASSWORD=|DB_PASSWORD=$mysqlpwd|" .env`.  NOTE: you need to be sure your password doesn't have `|` - you can use any other character (other than " :-)

Comment: `sed -i "s|DB_PASSWORD=|DB_PASSWORD=$mysqlpwd|" .env` that approach seems to work. Amazing. Thanks @MrR.

Comment: What was happening was you had some characters in the password that sed interpreted as special .. so if you had say `\1` or `&` or `|` you could have problems with this ...

Comment: Could you do away with passwords, or have a "less priviliged" DB user, or use certs (to do away with passwords? https://www.jetstack.io/blog/securing-mysql-with-cert-manager/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different delimiter for sed ... There are still risks of it failing depending on your actual password (e.g. if it included *|* or *&* or *\1*).

```
sed -i "s|DB_PASSWORD=|DB_PASSWORD=$mysqlpwd|" .env
```

Comment: And you wouldn't do this if the args to sed show up in ps, or sed was going to take a long time to process (because .env was massive and the disk was slow...)

Comment: I do not follow, sorry. Could you elaborate?

Comment: With the correct arguments to ps you can see everything passed on the command line .. in this case with the password ending up on the query string it is a risky thing - albeit because it happens so fast unlikely to be a consequential risk.

Comment: This would not work with a password containing `|`.

Comment: Correct - nor would it work with \1 or & either .. that is mentioned in the discussion on the question ..

Comment: Or any `sed` code that ends the current `s///` command and does _something else_.

Answer (score 2):

Passwords, by their very nature, must be allowed to contain *any character that can be reliably produced by a keyboard*.  This means that passwords can easily contain valid `sed` code, or strings that, when injected into a `sed` editing script, breaks that script, writes to arbitrary files on the system, or, with GNU `sed`, execute arbitrary commands (extra interesting when you're running as root, which you appear to be).

Don't use `sed` when you need to use user-supplied data, unless you know exactly how to sanitize it.  I would personally avoid `sed` for anything that would require me to double quote the `sed` expression (instead of single-quote it) to allow the shell to expand a variable that I had little control over.

Instead, use `awk`:

```bsh
awk -F '=' '
    BEGIN { OFS = FS }
    NR == FNR { password = $0; next }
    $1 == "DB_PASSWORD" { sub("=.*",""); $2 = password }; 1' /root/.mysql/db00.yml.db .env >.env.new &&
mv .env.new .env
```

This first reads the password from the first line of the first file (it's assumed that this only contains a single line with the verbatim password).

It then treats your `.env` file as a file of `=`-delimited fields.

When the first field on a line is `DB_PASSWORD`, it clears everything after the first `=` on the line (just in case the old password contains `=`), and  inserts the password in as the second field.

All lines, whether modified or not, are outputted to `.env.new`, and this file then replaces the old `.env` with `mv`.

Crucially, I never use the data read from either of the two files as *code* in my `awk` program, and I never allow `awk` to treat any part of the password as special. Note that using the password as the replacement string in a call to `sub()` would be problematic as this would treat any `&` in the string as special.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put passwords in command line arguments; they can be read by any user on the system via `ps` or `top` or many other ways.  I understand that may not be likely in some automation scenarios (because no one is likely to be logged into the box) but it's still a bad idea, and there's always the possibility that some monitoring tool or some script by someone else will happen to log the processes running on the system at some point in time—thereby logging your password to who knows where.

A good answer was already given using `awk`; I also wrote a simple solution using `ex` which I'll share.  This will work for any password with any special characters with the sole exception that it can't *end* in a backslash.

If file `.env` contains:

```
somevar1=someval
somevar2=some other val
DB_PASSWORD=
somevar3=another val
somevar4=val
```

And `myscript` contains:

```
/^DB_PASSWORD=$/a
!@#$#% some complicated password "^$%^&@#,.,cmxz\k'dvok][
.
0//j!
x
```

Just run `ex .env < myscript` to get results as shown:

```
$ ex .env < myscript
$ cat .env
somevar1=someval
somevar2=some other val
DB_PASSWORD=!@#$#% some complicated password "^$%^&@#,.,cmxz\k'dvok][
somevar3=another val
somevar4=val
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e "
  /^DB_PASSWORD=/c\\
DB_PASSWORD=$(sed -e 's:[\\]:&&:g' /root/.mysql/db00.yml.db)
"  ./.env
```

- We integrate within the sed code itself the sanitising of the password for plug worthiness in the change command `c\`